# How to make a chainable command in cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, cypress

Let's say I have a variable username.

Now, my chainable function wants to check if the username is empty or not.

Before:

```
if(username !== "") {
   cy.get('#username').type(username)
}
```

After (Expectation):

```
cy.get('#username').type(username).ifNotEmpty()        //ifNotEmpty will be my chainable func
```

So my question is Is this even possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: when adding `ifNotEmpty` to a chain, do you want to skip the previous `type` command? I think it's not possible. AFAIK, Cypress does not provide any public API to dismiss a previous command in the chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably just want to make a `.type()` variation

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('typeIfNotEmpty', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, textToType) => {
  if (textToType) {
   cy.wrap(subject).type(textToType)
  }
  return subject  // allow further chaining
})

cy.get('#username')
  .typeIfNotEmpty(username)
  .should(...)               // some assertion on '#username' element
```

Comment: Hey @Fody. I understood the logic but I am confused what "subject" mean here.

Comment: subject is just the element found from `cy.get('#username')`.

Comment: Got that. @Fody

Comment: Hi @Fody , Is it possible to create a chainable command without a prevSubject? For Example i take the selector as a string argument and return cy.get(selector)?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but you don't have to return the cy.get(selector) just call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom Cypress command to achieve this. These are called `child commands`. [More information here.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Child-Commands)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('ifNotEmpty', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  // code
})
```